# AudioSteamer's state sometimes doesn't change to AS_PLAYING

Tags: ios, audiostreamer

I use Matt Gallagher's AudioSteamer to implement the online music playing function,  I found that sometimes the online music is playing  but the audiostreamer's state doesn't change to AS_PLAYING, anybody meet the same problem? Can you tell me how to solve the question~~thanks~

I guess one of the reasons is that:

```
if (![[NSThread currentThread] isEqual:internalThread])
{
        [self
        performSelector:@selector(handlePropertyChange:)
        onThread:internalThread
        withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:inID]
        waitUntilDone:NO
        modes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
    return;
}
```

after those code execute in

```
- (void)handlePropertyChangeForQueue:(AudioQueueRef)inAQ
    propertyID:(AudioQueuePropertyID)inID
```

the function:

```
- (void)handlePropertyChange:(NSNumber *)num
{
    [self handlePropertyChangeForQueue:NULL propertyID:[num intValue]];
}
```

doesn't execute...
I really don't know how to fix it ...anybody help me?  thanks..

Comment: Have you fixed this ?

Comment: Is this issue resolved as yet...

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem. I added this code:

```
if (state == AS_WAITING_FOR_QUEUE_TO_START){
        @synchronized(self){
            self.state = AS_PLAYING;
        }
    }
```

Into the method:

```
- (void)handlePropertyChangeForQueue:(AudioQueueRef)inAQ
propertyID:(AudioQueuePropertyID)inID
```

just before this call:

```
[self
    performSelector:@selector(handlePropertyChange:)
    onThread:internalThread
    withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:inID]
    waitUntilDone:NO
    modes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
```